# SQL Reporting - Is it better to copy data first into a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting

We have tables in the following format:

```
Order(OrderID,CustomerID,OrderDate,CreatedByUserID,LastModifiedByUserID)
OrderItem(OrderID,ProductID,ProviderID,ItemStatus,CompletedByUserID)
Companies(CompanyID, CompanyName, CompanyParentID, CompanyRegionID)
```

The full data table required for generating reports for Orders requires almost 12 joins and about 250 fields. Below is a short example

```
SELECT o.OrderID, o.CustomerID ... FROM Orders AS o
INNER JOIN OrderItems AS items ON o.OrderID = items.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products AS p ON items.ProductID = p.ProductID
INNER JOIN Companies AS cust ON o.CustomerID = cust.ComapnyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Companies AS prov ON items.ProviderID = prov.ComapnyID
INNER JOIN Users AS u1 ON items.CreatedByUserID = u1.UserID
INNER JOIN Users AS u2 ON items.LastModifiedByUserID = u2.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users AS ui1 ON items.CompletedByUserID = ui1.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Users AS ui2 ON items.VerifiedByUserID = ui2.UserID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Companies AS parent ON cust.CompanyParentID = parent.ComapnyID
LEFT OUTER JOIN Companies AS region ON cust.CompanyRegionID = region.ComapnyID
```

**My question is:** SInce this is a reporting application, should we run this SQL once (e.g. every hour) and copy the data to a temp table from which the reports are run, or should we always run all these joins whenever a user requests to see the report?

**Note:**

1. The reports can be up to an hour out of date. Since they are typically run on a weekly/monthly basis.
2. The data is multi-tenant. i.e. it is filtered depending on who is running reports (customers, parent companies, regional offices, product providers etc.)

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not using a View to store the query and then run your report from that?

Comment: If the query takes a significant amount of resources to run, it is run frequently enough to be an issue, and the users can tolerate out-of-date data then it may make sense to cache the results. You can update the cache either at a regular interval or when a request is made and the cache content is determined to be too old. The first means that a user shouldn't have to wait for results (keeping the old data until the refresh completes), the second avoids the overhead of updating the cache when no one cares.

Comment: @betelgeuce I really hope you meant "indexed view"?

Answer (score 1):

It's always a good idea to separate OLTP and reporting tasks. Ideally in different DB instances.

But you must take into account, how recent data in reports should be.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you need, do you need the data to be completely up to date every time the report is run?  If not then you have a few options (I wouldn't use a temp table personally):

Cached Reports - You can get the report server to cache a copy of a report rather than generate it each time, it will get refreshed once the cached copy expires:

[Cache A Report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157447.aspx)

Report Snapshots - You can get the report server to create a snapshot of the data at a certain point in time, the reports will then run against this snapshot:

[Report Processing Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159241.aspx)

Ultimately what would be the best option if you have many of these types of reports with many joins etc is to implement a data warehouse type solution with a schema that is optimised for reporting, rather than the highly normalised schemas found in OLTP systems.